# Binary search 1/4 modification

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

My task is to write 1/4 - 3/4 binary search algorithm modification wherein the first element compared, when searching for  an item in the list, is the 'pivot' element which is at a distance of 1/4th from 
one end of the list(assuming the end chosen is the start of the 'remaining' 
list). If there is no match ('pivot' element is not equal to the search key) and 
if the part of the list that should be examined further for the search is 1/4th 
part of the list, continue with the same strategy. Whenever the part of the 
list that should be examined further for the search is of size 3/4th, switch to 
a binary search once and return to the 1/4th-3/4th strategy.
My code is here, but it doesnt work, and i dont know even if i am doing it right:

```
public static int ThreeFour(int[] Array,int item)
    {
       int counter =0;
       int high=Array.length-1;
       int low=0;
       int pivot = 0;

       boolean split = true;
       boolean last =true;

       while(high >= low) {
      if(split){
           pivot = (high+low)/4;
           last=true;}
       else
      {  pivot = (high+low)/2;
         split=true;
         last=false;
      }   

         if(Array[pivot] == item) 
         {  counter++;
         System.out.println("Pivot"+pivot);
         return counter;
         }

         if(Array[pivot] < item) {
          low = pivot + 1;
          counter++; 
         }

         if(Array[pivot] > item) {
          high = pivot - 1;
          counter++;
          if (last)
              split=false;
         }
       }
         return 0;   
    }
```

It doesnt work, maybe there is a simplier strategy to do that? The hardest part is to make it remember that it already splited in half once:/

Comment: `It doesnt work` Why? Compilation Error? Run time errro? wrong output? If it's giving wrong answer - please provide a test case + expected and actual result that demonstrates the issue. You should also use a debugger (or even better, split code to smaller methods and write unit-tests, bu debugger would be fine for now).

Answer (score 1):

Your formula to determine the pivot is wrong for the 3/4 split. If you want to split an interval between `low` and `high` at some point `c` with `0 <= c <=1`, you get:

```
pivot = low + c * (high - low)
      = (1 - c) * low + c * high
```

This wil give you `low` for `c == 0`, `high`for `c == 1` and for your 3/4 split:

```
pivot = 0.75 * low + 0.25 * high
```

or, with integer arithmetic:

```
pivot = (3 * low + high) / 4
```

In particular, the factors for `low` and `high` should sum up to 1.

I also think that your function has a logic error: You return the recursion depth, which has no meaning to the array. You should return the pivot, i.e. the array index at which the item is found. That also means that you can't return 0 on failure, because that's a valid array index. Return an illegal index like -1 to indicate that the item wasn't found.